# How to find the y coordinate of a cell in my UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableViewController with static cells.
In the method `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I'm hiding some cells by setting the rowHeight to 0.

**My Problem:**I'd like to find out what is the y coordinate of my last cell (not visible cell) so I can set a correct value in `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView` method

Comment: Did the solution helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly,

MaxY of the visible cell before the invisible cells = MinY of the visible cell after the invisible cells = MinY of the invisible cells = MaxY of the invisible cells

Therefore, you just need the row of any invisible cell and you can get the cell by

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexWithRow:row section:0]];
CGFloat y = CGRectGetMinY(cell.frame);
```